# Big time difference for compilation between`XeTeX and `pdfTeX` engines

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling

On Windows 7 64-bit I am using TeXLive 2016. I have the complete package installed and in order to use system fonts I switched from `pdfTeX` to `XeTeX`. It occurred to me that `XeTeX` ran much slower than its counterpart and the test in the `Windows PowerShell` confirmed this observation. For the same file with all the auxiliary files deleted **`XeTeX` takes 47 second to run, whereas `pdfTeX` takes 9 seconds.**

I read on this site that running `fc-cache -fv` in the administrator command prompt should help, yet this did not make the situation better. I know that it is acceptable to have a difference of %50 percent maybe, but the time it takes is nearly 5 times. What might be the reason behind this?

**PS:** The source file has a size of around ~1600 lines when flattened. The PDF output is 112-113 pages. The power shell output is below:

```
PS D:\Dropbox\Work\ThesisTeXSource> Measure-Command {pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode .\On
gunArisevMSc.tex}
system returned with code 1


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 97
Ticks             : 90973370
TotalDays         : 0.000105293252314815
TotalHours        : 0.00252703805555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.151622283333333
TotalSeconds      : 9.097337
TotalMilliseconds : 9097.337



PS D:\Dropbox\Work\ThesisTeXSource> Measure-Command {xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode .\Ong
unArisevMSc.tex}
system returned with code 1


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 47
Milliseconds      : 699
Ticks             : 476994194
TotalDays         : 0.000552076613425926
TotalHours        : 0.0132498387222222
TotalMinutes      : 0.794990323333333
TotalSeconds      : 47.6994194
TotalMilliseconds : 47699.4194



PS D:\Dropbox\Work\ThesisTeXSource>
```

Comment: Did you run this test once or is it representative?

Comment: @TeXnician I ran it more than once, it is similar every time. The compilation chain is `pdflatex -> biber -> makeindex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex` OR XeTex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why XeLaTeX is slower than pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329980/124577)?

Comment: @TeXnician So, might this be related with `xdvipdfmx` driver and totally normal behaviour?

Comment: @Vesnog Yes, because effectively it produces an intermediate format (DVI) and this is converted to PDF instead of pdflatex which omits the intermediate stage.